# Best way to go about biasing a Class B audio amplifier?

Tags: audio, amplifier, bias

I am trying to bias the class be audio amplifier in the provided pdf. None of the resistor values are correct so the bjts are unbiased. What is the best way to go about starting to bias this?

Circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJJ5D4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Can you circle R7 with a red line in the image above?

Comment: A good start would be to bias the base of the very first transistor to ground (not V+), assuming you want the no-signal output voltage to be zero. Eliminate the pullup on the second transistor's base, too. With the first stage DC-coupled to the second stage (the third transistor), it isn't clear why the third transistor has its own set of bias resistors. Can you provide a link to the document from which this diagram came?

Comment: Actually, it would be better to AC-couple the first stage to the second, since the second stage needs to have its base biased close to the negative rail in order to get reasonable voltage swing at the output.

Comment: What is a pullup? I am building this audio amplifier for a school project. This basic 3 stage circuit was given to me by a professor, so I am unsure why q3 has it's own set of bias resistors. Thanks.

Comment: A pullup is any resistor that connects a circuit node to the positive rail.

Comment: I believe we made the changes you suggested: http://i.imgur.com/vHjj32v.png                                                      Does that look okay? We biased the first transistor to ground (I think). We removed the pullup resistor on q2's base. And we ac coupled stage 1 to to stage 2.  Thanks.

Comment: @Sam Just in case you didn't know, you can embed CircuitLab schematics directly into the post.

Comment: Thanks. How do I go about doing that @AndrejaKo? Also @DaveTweed do the changes we made look correct. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Sam When you click on edit, you should find an icon next on the icon bar which had a diode, capacitor, resistor and a pen. It will say `Schematic Ctrl+M` when hovered over. You should be able to use `CTRL+M` to edit the schematic too.

Comment: Bias what? The output stage? The question is not clear. Did you build this and are trying to get it working, or just simulating it? What did you use for all the virtual components like current sources? Do you have a schematic of the device that has been built? Also, the diagram is not very readable at the posted resolution.

Comment: @Kaz The image is a problem with current implementation of CircuitLab embedding. It's automatically generated when circuit it linked. There's a pdf with high resolution [here](http://ge.tt/6ItiI3e/v/0).

Comment: @Kaz I would like to biase all of the bjts to make the Class B audio amplifier work. I apologize for the resolution of the schematic, but if you click simulate circuit it will open up in a new (much clearer window). Right now we are just simulating it before we purchase the components we need. We will design a simple constant current source that meets our needs when we actually build it. Thanks.

Comment: Let me know if the circuit lab link doesn't work. And yes I posted that pdf earlier today, but it isn't the most up to date version. Thanks

Comment: Do you really expect us to design this entire thing for you? You have a reasonable circuit topology, but nearly all of the component values are wrong, including the settings of the current sources and the transistor part numbers. Have you ever designed an amplifier before?

Comment: @DaveTweed I have never built one before. I was hoping for some information on how to get started. I don't want anyone to build the amp for me because I still want to learn, but I've never done this before and could use some guidance. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: You cannot apply global negative feedback across all these capacitively-coupled stages. It will oscillate like crazy due to the generous phase shifts.

Answer (score 1):

Your schematic is squished too small so that part values and designators can't be read, so I'll only answer in broad terms.

For starters, the input section is missing a deliberate DC bias.  You have AC coupled the input, which makes sense for a audio circuit, but added no deliberate DC bias of its own.  Only the middle stage has a deliberate DC bias, but this is AC coupled to the output stage so that bias does not follow to the output.

This circuit also can't seem to make up its mind whether it is meant to be single supply or not.  The three stages seem to be running from a single supply, but then the output is shown DC coupled to a load to ground, which makes no sense relative to the other parts.

To fix this mess, I'd start by adding some DC bias right after the input capacitor.  That should float the first stage at some reasonably predictable operating point.  Perhaps you can DC-couple the second and third stages, then use the DC of the output to bias the second stage.  This feedback would be filtered to only effect the DC operating point.  The AC feedback would still go back to the first stage as it does now.  Beware of instability though.

This kind of output stage will have a little crossover distortion.  You didn't give enough specs to determine whether that matters in this case.  If this is meant for high quality "hi-fi" operation, then you need to deal with it.  If it is meant for something less demanding, like a public address amplifier for example, then the overall feedback may deal with the crossover distortion well enough.  It won't be large, and for many basic applications that will be good enough, which allows keeping things considerably simpler.

In any case, you need to add small resistors in series with the emitter of each output transistor, else you can get large currents thru both and thermal runaway.

Answer (score 0):

> None of the resistor values are correct so the bjts are unbiased

That's not correct. The two diodes are already attempting to bias the two output transistors. It's not a good technique though. You need to investigate a thing called a 'bias spreader transistor', associated with a trimpot.

The resistor values are certainly all wrong as well, but that can't affect the output stage bias, as the output stage is AC coupled. They do affect bias of the second stage, but that's not class B so I assume that's not what you're talking about.

I would expect to see 0R1 to 0R33 at the emitter of each output transistor.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the more up to date (and squished) circuit the OP refers to in his comments and I've marked up in red the problems, and there are many of them: -

[image]

Biasing problem - bias needs to be centred on mid-rail except you have one of the supply rails upside down so there isn't a mid-rail.

All the current generators are ridiculously high in value.

Emitter resistor at  zero ohms - this can't be or a Q point near centre of the rails is never going to be achieved.

1N4148s are only rated at 200mA (which is fine if a sensible bias current for them were chosen).

Top o/p transistor is a 600mA max device whereas PNP is a 15A device.

I'm not going to even try designing any decent values until the OP is interested in putting the circuit into some sort of order and starts listening to folk and answering questions like "have you built it/simulated it?"